# iOS AVFoundation: video stuck at first frame sometimes (seems cross app)

Tags: ios, video, unity-game-engine

I am not directly using AVFoundation, but using AVPro in Unity, which i assume it's using AVFoundation to play video in ios. but i get some rare problem. the video is loaded, the meta data is correctly load, but it stucks at the same frame. there is no error returned. the app is not crash, but the video stuck. And then I find out this problem seems like cross app. When the problem appears, there is a chance another app with video feature also gets the problem.

Do someone also experience this? I am using iPad Air 2, iOS 10.0.2. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Does the same MP4 video work in any other iPad video player app?

Comment: it works in my app when it wants to work. If it doesn't want to work, then even other app like netflix, youtube can't work in my ipad.

Comment: Sounds like a hardware or internet problem not really a problem with your Unity code. Maybe [**this site**](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) can help you with such iPad issue (can use same account there, just click "Join this community" button at top).